# Override Mocha globals with Jest in directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, mocha.js

I have a repo where I am using cypress for E2E tests and Jest for unit/integration tests. The folder structure is similar to:

```
> src
    > utils
       time.ts
       time.spec.ts
> cypress
```

I am using jest for the tests in `src` and cypress is hard coded to use `mocha`

The current issue is - because cypress is exporting `mocha` as the default global for `describe` and `expect` - i have to explicitly import `describe`/`expect` from `@jest/globals`

Is there a config in either js, mocha or jest where i can specify only use mocha for `cypress` folder and jest for `src` folder?